# Use Algolia Instant Search with GeoJSON + React JS

Tags: reactjs, algolia, instantsearch.js, react-instantsearch

Does anyone know how to connect Algolia Instant Search with an API/database? In all their examples they have their data sets connected to "indexName"- see below: [image]

I can't seem to find how to configure a personal data set as an index.

Here is the link to the example repo I'm looking at: 
https://github.com/algolia/react-instantsearch/tree/master/examples/geo-search

Algolia: https://www.algolia.com/
Instant Search: https://www.algolia.com/products/instantsearch

Answer (score 0):

The Getting Started section of the Algolia Docs (Specifically the Indexing section) is likely a good place to start. This section will walk to you the various ways to create an index and fill it with data

https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/getting-started/what-is-algolia/
https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/indexing/indexing-overview/

Comment: You should add the essence of those links into your answer (links can be outdated)